Getting error while creating nestjs build
I have nestjs backend application, which i'm trying to deploy it on ubuntu based ec2, but getting following errors
cmd: sudo npm run build
Response:
> contentGPT@0.0.1 start
> nest start

/var/www/search-ai/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/build.action.js:85
        const webpackPath = (0, get_webpack_config_path_1.getWebpackConfigPath)(configuration, commandOptions, appName) ??
                                                                                                                         ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token '?'
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:915:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:963:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/search-ai/backend/node_modules/@nestjs/cli/actions/index.js:18:14)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)

I have tried in my local machine (macbook pro m2), it working fine there

Have you tried to remove node-modules directory and then npm/yarn install?

You can try putting your service into a Docker container to see if the error is really reproducible.

I guess that the issue is with Node version of the server.

I'm using latest node v21 version
